# Get first %p of column values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Suppose we have the table:

```
Students (First_Name, Last_Name, Section_Name, Grades_Avg)
```

I need to write a query that gets the first %p (parameter of a procedure) of students for each section with the atributes (First_Name, Last_Name, Section_Name, Grades_Mean), descending order after Grades_Avg, ascending after Last_Name, with the Grades_Avg > 5.

My work:

```
select First_Name, Last_Name, Section_Name, Grades_Avg 
from STUDENTS where Grades_Avg>5 
ORDER BY Section_Name, Grades_Avg DESC 
FETCH FIRST p PERCENT ROWS ONLY;
```

But with this I don't get for each Section_Name (the first %p) i get overall for all sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has a function called [`percent_rank()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions109.htm#i1043951), which *might* be able to help:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             percent_rank() over (partition by section order by grades_avg) as p_rank
      from students s
      where s.grades_avg > 5
     ) s
where p_rank <= p;
```

This assumes that `p` is a number between 0 and 1.  If it is between 0 and 100, then:

```
where p_rank <= p / 100
```

Note that students with the same grades have the same `p_rank` value, so they are with all included or all not included.

If you want an exact number returned -- for instance as close to 20% as possible even if all the students have the same grade, then `row_number()` and `count()` achieve that.

Comment: Hi, I tested your suggestion, but I think the last where p_rank <= p, this decides how many rows are returned per section. And for the percentage I think i should get all the rows (for the specific partition)  * p / 100. Is there a way to achive this?

Comment: @valer . . . I don't understand the comment.  `p_rank` is a ratio between 0 and 1.  If you want 20% of the rows, you want `p_rank <= 0.2`.  If you want to pass in `20` instead of `0.20`, then you use `p_rank < 20 / 100`.

Comment: sorry I was putting something else instead of percent_rank(). It works now. Thank you very much for your help.